# I don't understand the code for avoiding DoubleRenderError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The [official page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) has this snippet:

```
def show
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  if @book.special?
    render :action => "special_show" and return
  end
  render :action => "regular_show"
end
```

Why isn't this equivalent?

```
def show
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  if @book.special?
    render :action => "special_show"
    return
  end
  render :action => "regular_show"
end
```

Or, why isn't this used?

```
 def show
   @book = Book.find(params[:id])
   if @book.special?
     render :action => "special_show" and return
   else
     render :action => "regular_show"
   end
 end
```

I don't understand the need for `render ... and return`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They *are* in fact all equivalent.  Your example just happened to go with the least intuitively obvious version.  Not sure why, but that style is something I've seen frequently in Rails examples.

Essentially, `and` is a boolean operator with really low binding precedence, so a line like `expression_a and expression_b` will result in `expression_a` being evaluated, and then, as long as it didn't evaluate to `nil` or `false`, it'll evaluate `expression_b`.  Since `render` returns... well, something non-false -  don't know what, exactly ...your example behaves exactly like `render whatever; return` (or with a line break instead of the semicolon, like in the second snippet).

Personally, I prefer the third snippet, with the if/else block (which doesn't need the `and return`, 'cause it's at the end of the function anyway).  It's in-your-face obvious what it does, and I like that in my code.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

That's a really bad example. I'm really opposed to the `and return` method of short-circuiting because a lot of people don't understand what it means, and further, it's liable to be overlooked unless you're paying careful attention.

The better approach is as you describe where you have an explicit `if` statement that breaks out the two possibilities. I'd go one further to collapse this all into a single `render` call with the action argument identified ahead of time:

```
def show
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])

  # Determine the template to be used for this action
  render_action = @book.special? ? 'special_show' : 'regular_show'

  # Render the appropriate template
  render(:action => render_action)

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  render(:action => 'not_found', :status => :not_found)
end
```

Also missing from the example was the trap for the `find` call which can produce an exception if the record isn't found. This is a common over-sight and I'm pretty sure most people forget about it entirely. Remember you shouldn't be rendering 500 "server error" in a well designed app even when receiving bad requests.

The easiest way to avoid a double render error is to have only one `render` call, after all.

Comment: What about the return after the first render? Would that be wrong?

Comment: Don't rescue from `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`. Rails renders this as a 404 page by default ([source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb)).

Answer (score 1):

In the first snippet, if the `and return` was absent, and `@book.special?` was truthy, you would get a `DoubleRenderError`. That's because both the `render` calls would be executed.

With that in mind, all of the snippets are equivalent in that they will prevent `render` from being called twice. Also, in the last snippet, the `and return` is not needed since only one of the `render`'s will ever get called.